# Azure Mobile App obsolete?

Tags: azure, xamarin

We are currently running Azure Mobile App backend + Xamarin app as client and it works fine. Soon, we will be creating new mobile backend.

However, it would seem that, according to this 
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/issues/227

azure mobile apps is abandoned? Even Adrian Hall has moved to AWS? This begs the question, should I create mobile backend using WebApi 2 and deploy it as usual Azure Web App, use Azure Web App Mobile App?

Namechanging from Azure Mobile Service to Azure mobile app was confusing enough,there is also complete lack of up to date documentation for Azure mobile app SDK except from couple of examples.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm a PM in App Center team at Microsoft. I'd like to share our continued commitment to Azure Mobile Apps as our team own it. We are doing user research right now to understand the evolving needs for these services and plan to build the next generation of Azure Mobile Apps as part of Visual Studio App Center.

While we're working on the roadmap, we are fully committed to supporting Azure Mobile Apps including support for the latest OS releases, bug fixes, and documentation updates.

This is a similar pattern to what we are doing with HockeyApp and Xamarin Test Cloud. App Center is the next generation for those services and as we roll their functionality into App Center, we are re-imagining key developer workflows and adding new features, as well as integrating them into an end-to-end CI/CD solution that helps developers ship better apps faster.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So you would you recommend us to use Azure Mobile App for next mobile project(which will include Push notifications, and will have to handle very high traffic, we wont need table sync most likely), or to create regular WebApi2 project from scratch(.NET 4.6, OWIN) or go with .NET Core 2? I am asking this because I'm concerned that if we choose Azure Mobile Apps, and it gets discontinued/changed without backward compatibility in future we are left with dead project.

Comment: You can use Azure Mobile apps as it stands today but I want to add a clarification - Our plan is not to add new features in Azure Mobile Apps but really shape the next generation of this product by considering all the user feedback. Right now, we are in the very early phase of user research, so there is no commitment to the next-gen product in terms of timeline and backward compatibility. I want to set the right expectation so that you can make an informed decision on your end. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, @Ela. I'm here for the same concern plus we have encountered a lot of problems while developing our LOB using Azure Mobile App. 
Is there any update about the road map? Because we're thinking about alternatives like Firebase or AWS Amplify or even develop our own.

Answer (score 11):

I arrived here while looking for guidance on Xamarin.Forms offline sync feature in Azure Mobile Services.

Turns out Azure Mobile Services [has been superseded](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services) by Azure App Service Mobile Apps.  Fine, I'll look there for offline.

Turns out Azure App Service Mobile Apps has been superseded by Visual Studio App Centre.  This supports auth, data and push so I went looking for offline again.

Turns out App Center Mobile backend as a service (MBaaS) offering [is being discontinued](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/appcenter/app-center-mbaas-retirement/) so MS can focus on DevOps.

So in short if you want mobile backend service don't bother looking for MS to provide you a stable platform as a service, instead focus on building your own on their core products and hope they don't abandon those after a couple of years.

I hope these notes help sign-post the changes and demystify things a litte.

Comment: You've saved me tons of time. I am doing a pluralsight course that was created using VS 2017. I don't see any option to get an Azure Mobile Apps project.

Comment: Still in the same boat. I came looking for solutions for offline sync for our app and now so confused as there are so many obsolete/abandoned projects from Microsoft .. Sooooooo frustrating